# How to read event data properties

Tags: javascript, websocket

Below is the JavaScript code to read event properties:

```
function webSockStart() { // onclick() of a button
  document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;

  var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:3000/websock");

  ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    console.log(evt.data)
    console.log(evt.data["Key"]) // undefined
    console.log(evt.data["Val"]) // undefined

  };

}
```

---

`console.log(evt.data)` gives a string `"{"Key":"ab","Val":"cd"}"`(received through websocket)

`var map = new Map(JSON.parse(evt.data))` gives error: `Uncaught TypeError: object is not iterable(cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.Iterator))`

How to convert this string to a map object and read the properties?`console.log(evt.data["Key"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse it first and than you can access

```js
let str = `{"data" : {"Key":"ab","Val":"cd"}}`

let obj = JSON.parse(str)

console.log(obj.data['Key'])
```

Comment: @overexchange `Map` expects [iterable objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) `object` is not one of them. i am not sure why you want to change Object to Map ?

Comment: But am unable to compare table cells content with these parsed json `rows[i].cells[0].textContent == obj.data['Key']`. Because `console.log(obj.data['Key'])`  outputs `ab` but not `"ab"`

Comment: @overexchange what is `rows[i].cells[0].textContent` ?

Comment: `var rows = myTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")` and `console.log(rows[1].cells[0].textContent)` gives `ab` and `console.log(rows[1].cells[1].textContent)` gives `cd`

Comment: @overexchange you can console log and check the values. or create a working example than it will be easier to address exact problem

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501648/how-to-change-unchange-the-color-of-the-text-in-table-cell