# How to change color of the background in table cell for two seconds? and go back to default

Tags: javascript, css

In the below javaScript code:

```
        function webSocketStart()
        { //onclick() of a button
            document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;

            var wsock = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:1234/websock");

            wsock.onmessage = function (evt)
            {
                var map = JSON.parse(evt.data)

                var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
                var rows = myTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                var existing = false
                for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    if (rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length > 0) {
                        if (rows[i].cells[0].textContent.trim().localeCompare(map['Key'].trim()) == 0){
                            rows[i].cells[1].textContent = map['Value'] // cell color should change and unchange for two seconds
                            existing = true
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!existingApp){
                    var row = myTable.insertRow(1); // New row at the first position
                    var keyCell = row.insertCell(0)
                    keyCell.textContent = map['Key']
                    keyCell.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
                    setInterval(function(){
                        keyCell.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
                    }, 2000);

                    var valueCell = row.insertCell(1)
                    valueCell.textContent = map['Value']
                    valueCell.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        valueCell.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
                    }, 2000);
                }
```

---

Line 17, 26 & 27 have comments for color change and unchange

**Edit:**

Made code changes with `setTimeout()` but some cells does not change back to `white`

```
                for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    if (rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length > 0) {
                        if (rows[i].cells[0].textContent.trim().localeCompare(map['Key'].trim()) == 0){
                            rows[i].cells[1].textContent = map['Value']
                            rows[i].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow' // color change
                            existing = true
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                rows[i].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = 'white'
                            }, 2000);
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!existing){
                    var row = myTable.insertRow(1);
                    keyObj = row.insertCell(0)
                    keyObj.textContent = map['Key']
                    keyObj.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'  // color change
                    setInterval(function(){
                        keyObj.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
                    }, 2000);

                    keyObj = row.insertCell(1)
                    keyObj.textContent = map['Value']
                    keyObj.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'  // color change
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        keyObj.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
                    }, 2000);
                }
```

---

Using CSS & JavaScript,

1) How to change and unchange the color of the background in table cell, for 2 seconds? after setting of values in table cell

2)
As `table` element has style properties, Can we achieve the same without CSS rules? `rows[i].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'`

Comment: Do you want it to blink/flash for 2 seconds or just go yellow for 2 seconds then go back to the default?

Comment: @BryceHowitson Just go yellow for 2 seconds and then go back to the default. Am not using jQuery, as of now, as I have only one html element(`table`) and a button

Comment: I think your issues with `setTimeout()` not *APPEARING* to fire are due to scope. Things like `keyObj` likely don't exist for the function. I would create a "clear" function that the timer calls passed an argument containing the element to change.

Comment: Updated my answer to show what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You can just use sleep function with the seconds inside like sleep(2) for 2 seconds 
Is it what's you want

Comment: Does it affect the functionality of `wsock.onmessage` for messages coming from server? after sleep

Comment: `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`  goes in event queue that does not affect the functionality

Comment: yeah you can use it (setTimeout) on javascript and sleep on php

Comment: you can try with setInterval in a function and clearInterval in an other one

Comment: What do you mean other one? I tried with `setTimeout()` it does not work. some cells are going yellow forever. May be, you can show your idea through code.

Comment: try to look at this : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp
And thinking about set and clear

Comment: Why to set and clear using `setInterval()`? Isn't `setTimeout()` better than that? added code change in query

Comment: @overexchange `setTimeout()` is a self clearing interval

Answer (score 0):

You're already getting the element so you would add a class in JS like this:
`el.classList.add('className');` Then you need to set a timer `setInterval(function, milliseconds)` that removes the class after a set amount of time. The CSS will then revert back to default. I added a CSS transition to the color so it's not as jarring when it changes.

(click handler is just for the example)

```js
var removeClass = function(targ){
  if(targ.classList.contains('highlight')){
    targ.classList.remove('highlight');
  }
}

document.getElementById('myEl').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var myEl = this
  myEl.classList.add('highlight');
  var myTimer = setInterval(function(){removeClass(myEl)},2000);
});
```

```css
#myEl {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      margin: 10px;
      
      background-color: aqua;
      transition: background 0.25s ease;
      
     }
     
#myEl.highlight {
      background-color: orange;
     }
```

```html
<div id='myEl'></div>

Click the box to activate the timer
```